# Static files not served on Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I configured my website with an Application Load Balancer in front of everything, then I made 3 path rules that direct to 3 different beanstalks with php+linux2+nginx (target groups):

```
Application Load Balancer
/blog/* > wordpress-beanstalk
/app/* > app-beanstalk
others > main-beanstalk
```

So far each route is working fine, directing for the respective beanstalk application with main php code working. However, except for the "main-beanstalk", all static files (css,js,etc) from other applications are not being served, returning 403, 502 codes.

I suspect that for example when I access a page from "wordpress-beanstalk" the css file (mywebsite.com/blog/css/main.css) is being served from the "main-beanstalk" instead of the "wordpress-beanstalk", that is why is returning errors. As I cannot use relative paths on this case as well.

I also applied chmod -R 664 for these folders as well, which basic structure is like:

```
.platform
.exextensions
www
css
js
images
index.php
```

With this hypothesis, I tried to configure a static files config for the other applications with variations (removing slash, etc), however still doesn't work:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    "/images/": "/images/"
    "/css/": "/css/"
    "/js/": "/js/"
    "/lib/": "/lib/"
```

In addition, this is my location.conf file:

```
location / {
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Does anyone have any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

All your directories start with `slash`. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html) explicitly write not to do this:

> Specify a directory name in the root of your application's source code; **don't start it with a slash**.

Comment: Also tried exactly the same pattern of the example and still doesn't work, still receives 403,404, 502 errors from files